# [pixijs], [pixi.js] and [pixi]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

There are currently 3 tags for Pixi.js, [pixi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi), which is marked as synonym, [pixi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi.js), which has 276 questions, and [pixijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixijs) which has 12.

Do we really need all of these? Shouldn't they get merged?

Comment: It looks like [pixijs] should also be made a synonym.

Comment: What do you suggest the master tag should be?

Comment: @JonClements pixi.js, because it has the most questions

Comment: @JonClements [tag:pixijs] should be the main tag, since the official name is [PixiJS](http://pixijs.com). This is similar to [tag:angularjs].